# Appcelerator Titanium crashing too frequently?

Tags: windows-vista, titanium, appcelerator

I started using Appcelerator Titanium as its a promising platform for native desktop and mobile app development without sandbox (not like adobe air which is sandbox). But after a few days of development for no reasons it started crashing every time I launch my program on my Windows machine (with Vista). Then I found [this](http://www.jacobsingh.name/content/appcelerators-titanium-truncated-review) post too. Anyone having similar experiences with Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've had this happen as well. Some of my files weren't getting copied to my build directories so I deleted them.  Most of the time this worked fine as it just rebuilds them every time you run Titanium.  However, one day I did that at one point and it just stopped working.  That is what did it for me.

I also had one or two other odd things happen that were causing an issue like this. I think once I just created a new project and copied my files over :[  a little sad.

Overall I'm still a fan of the product. I can't imagine it just didn't work in Android. Must have have had multiple people having the issue but something specific to their setup or configuration.  Just possibly Appcelerator didn't have enough data from them to research it?

Comment: In my case, I used to restart Titanium Developer to solve this issue. But after 5-6 launches, it again starts crashing. No luck :(. Moreover I tried the sample kitchen sink app for Android (with Android SDK on Windows). Waited for 30 minutes but didn't get anything on the simulator screen. Don't know why? Does it take this long to launch the kitchen sink. My machine is quite equipped (dual core with 4GB RAM)

Comment: I wonder if it is possibly a Mac vs PC issue? It seems odd that it would be, but I would imagine a lot of their testing is probably more for Mac? Because they are making a pretty big iOS (ipad/iphone) push.  I use a Mac pretty much specifically for Titanium. Haven't tried to get the Kitchen Sink running on a PC, but have had success on the Mac.

Comment: They seem to have problems with race conditions in the tool-chain. On a Mac you usually have to press the Launch button several times as the tools just stop half of the time in the middle of something. Always have the "Filter" on "Trace" if it has stopped for more than a 10-15 seconds. Repress the Launch button.

Comment: Another hint. If the tiapp.xml file is touched (i.e just add a space in the file so the modification date and time is fresh) the complete project will be rebuilt. Solves some problems sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest version of Appcelerator Titanium Studio. 
Previous version has some problem like crashing when you clear console log and do similar certain stuff.

Download Link: https://platform.axway.com/#/product/studio

Thanks,